# XPath: Find Next Occurrence of an Element in an Ancestor

Tags: xpath, schematron

I am trying to find the next instance of  within a section of sec-type='reading'.

XML Sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<book>
    <sec sec-type="reading">
        <title>Section 1</title>
        <p>Sample <bold>Bold</bold>Text <fn><label>1</label></fn> Some more text</p>
        <!-- more variations of stuff at various levels -->
        <sec>
            <title>Section 1.1</title>
            <p>Another paragraph with a footnote <fn><label>2</label></fn></p>
        </sec>
        <sec>
            <title>Section 1.2</title>
            <p>Another paragraph with a footnote <fn><label>3</label></fn></p>
        </sec>
    </sec>

    <sec sec-type="reading">
        <title>Section 2</title>
        <p>Sample <bold>Bold</bold>Text <fn><label>6</label></fn> Some more text</p>
        <!-- more variations of stuff at various levels -->
        <sec>
            <title>Section 2.1</title>
            <p>Another paragraph with a footnote <fn><label>8</label></fn></p>
        </sec>
        <sec>
            <title>Section 2.2</title>
            <p>Another paragraph with a footnote <fn><label>9</label></fn></p>
        </sec>
    </sec>
</book>
```

The purpose is to see if the FN labels are sequentially ordered within a section. I've numbered the second section with 6-9 to make it easier to see if it's working.

This is what I want:

```
Footnote 1 [Next: 2]
Footnote 2 [Next: 3]
Footnote 3 [Next: ]
Footnote 6 [Next: 8]
Footnote 8 [Next: 9]
Footnote 9 [Next: ]
```

The eventual goal is to return a warning for `Footnote 6 [Next: 8]`

This is the schematron I've got so far. This gives me:

```
Footnote 1 [Next: 2]
Footnote 2 [Next: 3]
**Footnote 3 [Next: 6]**
Footnote 6 [Next: 8]
Footnote 8 [Next: 9]
Footnote 9 [Next: ]
```

It finds the next instance of the footnote. However, I don't want it to cross the sections - so `Footnote 3 [Next: 6]` is wrong.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    queryBinding="xslt2"  >

  <!--check if footnotes are sequential within a reading -->
  <pattern id="footnote-sequential"> 
    <rule context="fn"> 
        <let name="next" value="following::fn[1]/label/text()"/>

        <assert test="number(label/text()) > 40">
        Footnote <value-of select='label'/> 
          [Next: <value-of select="$next"/>]
      </assert>
    </rule> 
  </pattern>
</schema>
```

Note: `number(label/text()) > 40` in the assert is there to catch everything at the moment. It'll eventually be something along the lines of `number(current)+1 != number(next)`

The closest I've gotten is `ancestor::sec[@sec-type='reading']//following::fn[1]/label/text()` - but that looses the "next" and gives me weird results like this:

```
    Footnote 1 [Next: 1236]
    Footnote 2 [Next: 1236]
    Footnote 3 [Next: 1236]
    Footnote 6 [Next: 689]
    Footnote 8 [Next: 689]
    Footnote 9 [Next: 689]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `intersect`.

**[EDIT]**

Set `$next` to the `fn` element instead of the label text:

```xml
<let name="next" value="following::fn[1]"/>
```

**[/EDIT]**

Go to your current section and take all footnotes of this section:

```xml
<let name="sect-fns" value="ancestor::sec[@sec-type='reading']//fn" />
```

Make the intersect on `$next` and `$sect-fns`:

```xml
<let name="next" value="$next intersect $sect-fns" />
```

Check if `$next` is empty or its label is `number(./label) + 1`:

```xml
<assert test="not($next) or number(./label) + 1 = number($next/label)">
```

Comment: your answer works, but it has a typo I'm forbidden from fixing by the overlords on the site. Change the variable name for mine ($next) to $next_fn and make yours $next_fn_inSec. So your answer would look like:

Make the intersect on $next_fn and $sect-fns:

`<let name="next_fn" value="following::fn[1]"/>
<let name="next_fn_inSec" value="$next_fn intersect $sect-fns" />`

Check if $next_fn_inSec is empty or its label is number(./label)+1:
`<assert test="not($next_fn_inSec) or number(./label)+1 = number($next_fn_inSec/label)">`

Comment: It was not a typo, I just incorrectly assumed, that `$next` is the `fn` element, not label text. I fixed that in my answer.

Comment: you are absolutely right. Somehow I had convinced myself that you couldn't redefine a variable in xslt/schematron. When I first tried your answer I must have typed something wrong and incorrectly assumed that was the problem. Thanks again for your answer!